# Use an existing Gateway with Azure Machine Learning?

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

We want to access an onprem SQL database with an existing Gateway, is that possible in AML?  The tool only seems to allow creating new gateways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confirmed that this is not possible, AML only allows use of AML-created gateways.